# array with implode and explode

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array.

```
 Array(
    [deselected_attachment_ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16883477_12869438
        [1] => 16883478_12869439
    )
)
```

Required output from array = array( 12869438,12869439);

I used following code.

```
 $implodeArray = implode(',',$testArray);
```

It gives me warning

```
Array to string conversion
```

How should I get required output array?

Comment: I think that just `$testArray['deselected_attachment_ids']` will do. You could use `array_values`, see [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php)

Comment: @Lucho no, the OP want to have the 2nd half of each of the values in the subarray.  `array_values()` is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode to split string to two parts and get the 2nd

```
$res = array_map(function($x) { return explode('_', $x)[1]; },
                 $arr['deselected_attachment_ids']);
print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/933701)

Comment: any optimised solution than array_map?

Comment: Why not array_map?

Answer (score 0):

You can let `preg_replace()` traverse the array for you and remove the unwanted parts.  While regex isn't known for being fast, it is a direct, one-function solution.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f38b41fed205729b75b32ed734ec25b6bb97e879))

```
$array=['deselected_attachment_ids'=>['16883477_12869438','16883478_12869439']];
$result=preg_replace('/^\d+_/','',$array['deselected_attachment_ids']);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '12869438',
  1 => '12869439',
)
```

Or you can use a `foreach` loop with `explode()`: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64758a7099ddcd96473ed86401fc284148415f68))

```
$array=['deselected_attachment_ids'=>['16883477_12869438','16883478_12869439']];
foreach($array['deselected_attachment_ids'] as $v){
    $result[]=explode('_',$v)[1];
}
var_export($result);
// same result
```

And finally, if you don't want to use regex and you don't want to generate temporary arrays (from `explode()` call) on every iteration, you can use `substr()` and `strpos()`.

```
$array=['deselected_attachment_ids'=>['16883477_12869438','16883478_12869439']];
foreach($array['deselected_attachment_ids'] as $id){
    $result[]=substr($id,strpos($id,'_')+1);
}
var_export($result);
```